# SSIS Creating a multiline DOS file

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have to create a multiline DOS batch file in SSIS that looks like this:

```
cd e:\client\data
copy generic_output.txt clientname.yyyymmdd
```

where `yyyymmdd` is today's date

I have created quite a few single line DOS copy statements which do the copy *(using a Derived column in the Data Flow)* but can't come up with an approach that will allow me to create a template file that contains the (hardcoded) first line and then have a Data Flow task which writes out the first line and then have the Derived column be the second line.

Can I write out both commands in the Derived Column and put in a CR-LF in between the `cd` command and the `copy` command? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Which version of DOS are you using, FreeDOS, DR-DOS, ROM-DOS, PTS-DOS, RxDOS REAL/32 or MS-DOS, _which was last seen in Windows ME as v8.0_?

Comment: Why not using a script component to achieve this?

Comment: You can concatenate commands onto one line by using an ampersand between each command. `cd /D e:\client\data & copy generic_output.txt clientname.yyyymmdd`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works. The cd command is fixed so I put that into a file. Then I used a Data Flow to build the COPY command in another file. Then I set up a copy.bat file to copy the 2 files, and then finally an Execute Process task to execute the final batch file. It works.

Thanks,

Dick